# Copy folder with same name in Powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

I want to copy folders subfolders and files from Source to Destination for e.g. `D:\WIP\letsc` to `D:\WIP\letsc1`. Please note that the destination subfolder has the same name as the source folder. I have this so far but it fails on line 4.

From the third line of code it creates a directory on whatever it finds under $CreateFolderPath at the destination and then it should copy the same folder to destination.

```
$CreateFolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\WIP\letsc" 
foreach ($directory in $CreateFolderPath) {
New-Item -Path D:\WIP\letsc1\$directory -ItemType Directory -force
Copy-Item -recurse $directory -Destination D:\wip\letsc1\$directory -Force
}
```

To simplify the situation `D:\WIP\Letsc\ECBREG64` should be copied to `D:\WIP\LetsC\ECBREG64\ECBREG64`.

I am newbie to powershell so please excuse me if my requirement is a bit paranoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$Directory` here will be an object with all properties and method for `fileinfo` and `directoryinfo`.

You could do a `$CreateFolderPath | Get-Member` to see all possible properties and members for the respective outputtypes, so that you can use the relevane items from it.

For you issue, you need the fullname of the file/directory while copying and the BaseName while creating the folder.

```
$CreateFolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\WIP\letsc" 
foreach ($directory in $CreateFolderPath) {
New-Item -Path "D:\WIP\letsc1\$($directory.BaseName)" -ItemType Directory -force
Copy-Item -recurse $directory.FullName -Destination "D:\wip\letsc1\$($directory.BaseName)" -Force
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks this works. Never thought of .fullname and .basename properties.

Comment: You can mark this as answer and close the thread, This will help others.

Comment: Thanks Prasoon i did.